# How to force functions of thumb2 instruction set begin at 32 bits alignment address?

Tags: arm, thumb

There are 16 bit and 32 bit instructions in thumb2 instruction set. Functions may begin at 16 bit or 32 bit alignment address. Is there a way to make all functions begin at 32 bit alignment address?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GCC I think you can just pass -falign-functions=4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not using GCC and I can not find the option has the same meaning of armcc.